# Creating mail account not a mailbox using imap in php

Tags: email, imap, pop3, mx-record

We all know how to open a mailbox using `imap_open`. Here the problem is i'm creating a maill system here. I'm not able to find to create a mail account with `imap/pop3` in `php`. Is it is possible ?

Assume suppose my domain is www.studentmug.com. I want to create a mail for another user with out using cPanel. Ex:- `radhakrishna@studentmug.com`. I'm not finding any script for it in `IMAP` section. could any one got this problem or solution ?

Please share your opinions & suggestions -  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are on wrong way, you can not use [`IMAP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol) or [`POP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol) protocol commands to create a new user account. `IMAP` or `POP` protocols are used to access mails from existing mailbox on server.

Probably you should check whether any CLI command library is provided by your domain service provider or not. It it provides any CLI support than you can create a new email account with those commands (without using cPanel).

Note that you can create a new mailbox using [imap_createmailbox](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.imap-createmailbox.php), but can not add new user account.

Answer (score 0):

Setup the imap server to authenticate using MySQL and create the accounts in a MySQL database using PHP. Dovecot is a decent email server for this.